# Is is possible to get a Channels social links with the Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

On a Youtube channel page there are links of to related sites. Is it possible to get these through the Youtube API or will I have to parse the page.

[image: Related links on Youtube channel]

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately 'related sites' are not provided in API, even in "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.description"

Comment: Ibrahim, are they still unavailable?

Comment: @Ibrahim, is it still not available?

Answer (score 1):

I created a very simple Java-API which can get the related sites from a Youtube channel. It will return all the URLs and the link texts. You can even filter out the links for a specific website or social network.

```
YoutubeRelatedSites yrs = new YoutubeRelatedSites(new URL("https://www.youtube.com/user/WatchMojo/about?&ab_channel=WatchMojo.com"));
Map map = yrs.getLinks(); //Get all related sites
URL[] twitterLinks = yrs.getTwitter(); //Get all twitter links
```

Download the source code here: https://github.com/Grunzwanzling/YoutubeRelatedSites