# How to get link with Youtube Api v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Do you know how to get link from about page of user channel? Twitter, facebook...
I need of special permission?
for example: https://www.youtube.com/user/RihannaVEVO/about
Best regards

Comment: Try the solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822009/how-to-get-user-links-through-youtube-api). You can also visit the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/documentation/) for further reference.

Comment: Thank but that post is very old

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to fetch the "About" section details on a Youtube channel page through Youtube Data API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170409/how-to-fetch-the-about-section-details-on-a-youtube-channel-page-through-youtu/68779548#68779548)