# How to fetch the "About" section details on a Youtube channel page through Youtube Data API?

Tags: google-apis-explorer, youtube-data-api

I've been exploring the Youtube Data API but I am not able to find any endpoint that returns the "About" section details for a channel. Is there any particular endpoint that can provide me this response? My use case is to basically find the twitter link of the channel which is mostly present in the "About" section.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Data API v3 doesn't seem to give any tool for this.

What I would recommend is using a minimal working curl request like:

```bash
curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/BenjaminLoison/about' -H 'Cookie: CONSENT=YES+'
```

Comment: [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73908946/7123660) contains more information.

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list appears to contain "description" when you specify "snippet" for the part.